# GCP Dataflow Kafka and missing SSL certificates

Tags: nlp, python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

I'm trying to fetch the data from Kafka to Bigquery using GCP Dataflow.
My Dataflow template is based on Python SDK 2.42 + Container registry + apache_beam.io.kafka.

There is my pipeline:

```
def run(
        bq_dataset,
        bq_table_name,
        project,
        pipeline_options
        ):

    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        kafka = pipeline | ReadFromKafka(
            consumer_config={
                'bootstrap.servers': 'remote.kafka.aws',
                'security.protocol': "SSL",
                'ssl.truststore.location': "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts",
                'ssl.truststore.password': "changeit",
                'ssl.keystore.location': "/opt/apache/beam/kafka.keystore.jks",
                'ssl.keystore.password': "kafka",
                "ssl.key.password": "kafka",
                "ssl.client.auth": "required"
            },
            topics=["mytopic"]
        )
        kafka | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(bq_table_name, bq_dataset, project)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = get_logger('beam-kafka')
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--bq_dataset',
        type=str,
        default='',
        help='BigQuery Dataset to write tables to. '
             'If set, export data to a BigQuery table instead of just logging. '
             'Must already exist.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--bq_table_name',
        default='',
        help='The BigQuery table name. Should not already exist.')

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args, save_main_session=True, streaming=True)

    project = pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project
    if project is None:
        parser.print_usage()
        print(sys.argv[0] + ': error: argument --project is required')
        sys.exit(1)

    run(
        known_args.bq_dataset,
        known_args.bq_table_name,
        project,
        pipeline_options
    )
```

Here is how I execute and run this pipeline:

```
python stream_kafka.py \                                                                  
    --bq_dataset=test_ds \
    --bq_table_name=test_topic_data \
    --project=xxxx \
    --region=us-east4 \
    --runner=DataflowRunner \
    --experiments=use_runner_v2 \
    --sdk_container_image=$IMAGE \
    --job_name="test_kafka" \
    --no_use_public_ips \
    --disk_size_gb=100
```

All the certificates I added to Dockerfile:

```
COPY --chmod=0755 truststore.der /etc/ssl/certs/truststore.der
COPY --chmod=0755 kafka.keystore.p12   /opt/apache/beam/kafka.keystore.p12
RUN keytool -import -trustcacerts -file truststore.der -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -alias kafka \
        -deststorepass changeit -noprompt
RUN keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore kafka.keystore.p12 \
                        -srcstorepass kafka \
                        -srcstoretype pkcs12 \
                        -destkeystore /opt/apache/beam/kafka.keystore.jks \
                        -deststorepass kafka \
                        -keypass kafka \
                        -deststoretype jks
```

The issue is when I'm trying to run Dataflow, it couldn't find kafka.keystore.jks:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:69) ... 43 more Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /opt/apache/beam/kafka.keystore.jks of type JKS org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder$SecurityStore.load(SslEngineBuilder.java:292) org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslEngineBuilder.createSSLContext(SslEngineBuilder.java:144) ... 46 more Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/apache/beam/kafka.keystore.jks java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
```

Comment: Have you checked the image to make sure the keystore.jks file exists in the specified location?

Comment: Yes, I double-checked my custom image and even docker containers that were created by dataflow. Dataflow created several containers inside the worker, but only one of these containers does NOT have my keystore files. This is weird container because it contains openJDK11 and python3.9, BUT I didn't specify this parameters in my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You should ingest certificates into Java SDK, not into Python. So, I created one more docker image but based on Java SDK:

```
FROM openjdk:11

COPY --from=apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.42.0 /opt/apache/beam /opt/apache/beam

COPY ./ca.txt /usr/src/ca.txt
COPY ./cert.txt /usr/src/cert.txt
COPY ./key.txt /usr/src/key.txt

ENV CA_CERTS="/usr/local/openjdk-11/lib/security/cacerts" 

ENV ROOT_FILE=/usr/src/ca.txt
ENV CERT_FILE=/usr/src/cert.txt
ENV KEY_FILE=/usr/src/key.txt
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /scripts/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /scripts/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/scripts/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

After that, I implemented converting my certificates into Java format(JKS) inside `entrypoint.sh` file. And use an additional parameter while running dataflow to overwrite Java(harness) image: `--sdk_harness_container_image_overrides=".*java.*,${IMAGE_JAVA}"`

Hope it will help anyone.